# How to find the Pi subscript

Tags: python, python-2.7, character

I tried to find out, in which digit does any given name occurs. code goes like,

```
iterator = 97
int_lis = []
lis = []
lis.append('@')

for item in range(iterator,iterator+26) :
    lis.append(chr(item))

name = raw_input('\n Enter your name\t')

for item in name:
    int_lis.append(lis.index(item))
print int_lis

match =" "

for item in int_lis:
    match = match + str(item)
print match

f = open("pi.txt","r")
content = f.read()

print  content.find(match)
#print content.find("494")  This line seems to give output.
```

it always returns -1, no matter what the input is.

"pi.txt" is the content of http://www.piday.org/million/

what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `match` has a whitespace in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You started `match` with a space:

```
match =" "
```

Use an empty string instead:

```
match = ""
```